# Some of Product name is not showing on front-end anonymously

Tags: magento-1.8, products, frontend-error

Products are not newly added it's not showing on listing page only . product page it's shown. it's working fine (e.g product listing page) everywhere except product tab

[image]

Comment: please check your list.phtml file for that I think this probelm is related to reindex reindex data or check once disabling the flat table and clear the cache.

Comment: I did same disabled/enable (disabling already) the flat table and check list.phtml  but problem with reindexing.. how to debug problem @MurtuzaZabuawala

Comment: Have you inspected the view source or such to determine if the content is being generated and possibly hidden by CSS/JS?

Comment: @B00MER Yes I inspected content is not generated for some of products only . Not hidden by css/JS.

Comment: reindex all data. if you are using flat tables cause this issue.

Comment: you have given names in this language or in the English at admin side

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Japanese language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I solved it..  problem is `Strip Html Tags` and `max length` of title nameAs it's in the `Japanese language` so it validates name more than 30 characters..  when I increase the length of  display tag it's appeared (title)

Answer (score 1):

in your list page instead of below code

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

try this code

```
<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>
```

I think there should some problem with locale that's why you have this problem try my way and let me know

Comment: @lalitmohan If possible send me the url